# Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined with version 2.3.0 and plain JS

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I need to generate a PDF report from a table and I am using jsPDF along with jsPDF-autotable.
I know it's very simple to generate a PDF file with jsPDF and I believe that I am following the exact steps mentioned on jsPDF documentation page, but I haven't got any success so far. I have also gone through many similar questions but none seems to be working for me.

Here is how I have imported jsPDF and jsPDF-autotable in html head tag:

```
<!-- Js PDF -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<!-- Js PDF Auto Table -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jspdf-autotable@3/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my html code code for the button which should trigger a JavaScript function:

```
<div class="col text-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnGenerateReport" onclick="prepareReport()">
            Generate Report
        </button>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript function which should just generate a PDF file based on a table:

```
function prepareReport() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#reportTable' });
    doc.save(stationSelected + '_' + dateSelected + '.pdf');
}
```

And here is the console error I am getting:

```
reports.js:180 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
at prepareReport (reports.js:180)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (reports:213)
```

I would truly appreciate all the help I can get.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your function:

```js
function prepareReport() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#reportTable' });
    doc.save(stationSelected + '_' + dateSelected + '.pdf');
}
```

Importing this module using the  tag like you are doing, after reviewing the [jsPDF project repo](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), exports the global variable as `jspdf`, not `jsPDF`.

So the correct working version should be:

```js
function prepareReport() {
    var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({ html: '#reportTable' });
    doc.save(stationSelected + '_' + dateSelected + '.pdf');
}
```

Note that this code alone is not enough, because `stationSelected` and `dateSelected` are not defined. You should also provide definitions for these values.

Live [codepen](https://codepen.io/tmilar/pen/MWbOXox) working example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked nicely. I agree with you on jspdf (not jsPDF) part. However, I didn't see it mentioned anywhere on the documentation.

I saw this though: `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";`, but it was giving an error, do you know why we can't import like that in JS, or there is a different way to do that?